# Swift: Can I change a variable to a CGRect when a SpriteNode touches any CGRect?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgrect

I am creating a sort of maze where it's made up of lots of `CGRects` so that when the `SpriteNode` touches a side of the `CGRect` the `SpriteNode` knows not to cross it.

So far I just have a list of if statements to verify it. But is there a way to make it more streamlined?
The ways that I think that it could work is where you have a constant variable:

`let rectangle = CGRect.contains(SKSpriteNode.position)`

and that would be the rectangle that the SKSpriteNode Touches but obviously that wouldn't work.

Comment: With contains, you can check if one particular CGRect contains a single point, like position. That returns a boolean. Maybe if your maze is small, you can check everyone and determine which is touched :) It is worth mentioning that there are more advanced techniques within SpriteKit such as raycasting and collisions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This sounds like a situation where you should be using Sprite-Kit's contact detection, so that a function in your code gets called if the sprite touches one of your rectangles.

Comment: You are asking for some more streamlined code, but you haven't included the code you are using. Also, your question isn't clear - the title mentions changing a variable to a CGRect (but the code you post already returns a CGRect) and in your text your ask if your code can be streamlined. Also is something not working or re you just asking if there is a more efficient technique?